# How to troubleshoot this simple SQL query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm still pretty new to SQL and I don't understand why this query comes back with 0 results. When I look at the dataset there are hundreds of results for THEFT BY SHOPLIFTING but none show up here. What I aim to do is pull only the Shoplifting data by zipcode and make a map viz on Tableau.

```
SELECT
  *

FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime

WHERE year = 2016
  
AND description = "THEFT BY SHOPLIFTING"
  
AND zipcode IS NOT NULL
 
ORDER BY
  zipcode

LIMIT 10000;
```

[Screenshot of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkH6T.png)

Comment: Sorry, I see now that your screenshot contains the same query already included in your question. However, we cannot debug a query for you that runs against tables for which we have no structure or contents. Please edit your question to include the relevant table structure and sample contents you're trying to match.

Comment: the query in question actually reference publicly available table and anyone with GCP account has access to it!! so I vote to reopen question as it has quick simple answer!

Comment: all he needs is a trim function like this: SELECT
  *

FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime`

WHERE year = 2016
  
AND trim(description) = "THEFT BY SHOPLIFTING"
  
AND zipcode IS NOT NULL
 
ORDER BY
  zipcode

LIMIT 10000;

Comment: break it down.  Remove your where clause and do a count(*) in your select.  add back in each line in the where clause until the count returns (0) then you know that line is the problem.  The question is do you have data meeting the critieria you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings can be pesky for sure -- looks like trailing characters is potentially your issue.

Try this:

```
SELECT
  *

FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_crime.crime

WHERE year = 2016
  
AND description like "%THEFT BY SHOPLIFTING%"
  
AND zipcode IS NOT NULL
 
ORDER BY
  zipcode

LIMIT 10000;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that suggestion did populate a result that I was expecting. I have never used % or "like" before in a query and will need to research why this worked, tbh. Thank you for your patience - I am still quite new and don't even know what info to include in my questions on Stack. Thanks so much, have a great week.